# How to use $date in Unix script

Tags: unix, shell-script

I'm using `$date` command in a Unix script and it is giving as "Tue Aug 27 05:53:37 EDT 2013".

This is coming as an automatic mail.

The timestamp value is long and it wraps to new line.

How can I adjust command such that time format does not wrap into new line?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

If you do `man date`, you will find all possible placeholders to construct your date string.

Answer (score 1):

`man date` shows all possible output options, you coud for example use

```
$ date +%D
09/11/13
```